# Asp.net report viewer publishing on IIS

Tags: asp.net, report, infragistics

I have crated a web page on Asp.net web form applications. I added a Infragistics ReportViewer in my project,after I added a silverlight application in my project ,On Silverlight app. I will show my reprt viewer.My project is running succesfuull on visual studio when I run it with F5. Now I will publish my project on IIS. I published my project in a folder WebSite1.

Here İs my code (silverligt properties code ):

```
<ig:XamReportViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="280" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="380">
            <ig:XamReportViewer.RenderSettings>
                <ig:ServerRenderSettings DefinitionUri="/ornek;component/Report1.igr" ServiceEndpointUri="http://localhost:52237/ReportService1.svc/soapAddress"/>
            </ig:XamReportViewer.RenderSettings>
        </ig:XamReportViewer>
```

My Report Srvice running on IIS with this url :

```
http://hacegan/WebSite1/ReportService1.svc
```

So refreshed my project code tı :

```
<ig:XamReportViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="280" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="380">
            <ig:XamReportViewer.RenderSettings>
                <ig:ServerRenderSettings DefinitionUri="/ornek;component/Report1.igr" ServiceEndpointUri="http://hacegan/WebSite1/ReportService1.svc/soapAddress"/>
            </ig:XamReportViewer.RenderSettings>
        </ig:XamReportViewer>
```

But when I willa cces my page it comes an error on silverligt application that :

Cannot establish a connection wtih the report server

what can I do or what I must write to this line

```
<ig:ServerRenderSettings DefinitionUri="/ornek;component/Report1.igr" ServiceEndpointUri="http://localhost:52237/ReportService1.svc/soapAddress"/>
```

Comment: What is the exact response from the server if you use a tool like fiddler to look at the network traffic and see the response?